# How can I login to Google Search without logging into Google Maps?

Tags: google-search, google-maps

I would like to use my search settings with Google Search. I would like to stop getting "customized" results in Google Maps. Is there a way to login to Google Search without logging into Google Maps? Or logout of Google Maps without logging out of Google Search?

Comment: You'd need two browsers, if not 2 devices. One logged in, the other not - & also probably on private browsing. Google can be pretty insidious at following you though.

Comment: If you are logged in with your Google account then both Search and Maps will use the same account. You might try to to use Maps in incognito mode. Like that the results won't be linked to your account.